# Setting element width() does not work with a variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, width

I'm trying to set an element width using jQuery and it just won't work.

Here is my code:

```
var $padding = 30,
$oddWidth = parseInt( Math.round( $(window).width()*0.75 ) ),
$odd = $oddWidth-$padding;

$('div:jqmData(role="content")').css({ 'margin-left':'25%'}).width( $odd );
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: This is working for me in my quick jQuery.mobile test. What exactly is not working and are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: It's working for me!
http://jsfiddle.net/Dg5qV/2/
Maybe it is your selector?

Comment: There's no errors in the console and the margin-left 25% is assigned. So it can't be init- or selector-related. Also if I'm using width('123px') or width('75%') they are also assinged. I don't get why it cannot be a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is working for me, so are you wrapping the jQuery code inside the following?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pageshow',function(){
        var $padding = 30,
        $oddWidth = parseInt( Math.round( $(window).width()*0.75 ) ),
        $odd = $oddWidth-$padding;
        $('div:jqmData(role="content")').css({ 'margin-left':'25%'}).width( $odd );
    });
});
```

jQuery.mobile has a different [`document.ready()`](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/) for when a "page" is fully loaded, so perhaps without this, the `width()` is not correct or the `<div data-role="content">` does not exist yet.

Comment: Found it... the code was inside an if-else statement and I declared both the variables inside the if part and did this formatting in the else-part... :-| Still, THANKS!, because copy-pasting your code made me recognize it.